# Number of Customers Grouped By number of orders with Revenue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to build a query that will give me the number of orders grouped by the quantity made plus I would like the revenue for those numbers.

So for example.

```
| Number of Orders  | Numbers of Customers  | Revenue Of Orders  |
| 1                 | 312                   | 4350.88            |
| 2                 | 208                   | 3490.00            |
| 3                 | 152                   | 2240.50            |
```

I have got the first two columns working correctly.. This is that query

```sql
SELECT
    r.num_of_orders ,
    count(*) AS num_of_customers
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            count(*) AS num_of_orders
        FROM
            reservations r
        WHERE
            created_at >= '2008-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND `status` = 'closed'
        GROUP BY
            r.customer_id
    ) r
GROUP BY
    r.num_of_orders
```

Trying to add revenue I have tried.

```
SELECT
    r.num_of_orders ,
    count(*) AS num_of_customers,
    sum(b.total) as total_revenue
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            count(*) AS num_of_orders
        FROM
            reservations r
        WHERE
            created_at >= '2008-01-01 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY
            r.customer_id
    ) r,
    (
        SELECT
            sum(payments.total) AS total
        FROM
            reservations r
        JOIN payments ON payments.id = r.reservation_id
        WHERE
            r.created_at >= '2008-01-01 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY
            r.customer_id
    ) b
GROUP BY
    r.num_of_orders
```

But I know these numbers for revenue are out..

Hope you can advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it in the original subquery:

```
SELECT r.num_of_orders, count(*) AS num_of_customers,
       SUM(revenue) as total_revenue
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r.reservation_id) AS num_of_orders,
             SUM(p.total) as revenue
      FROM reservations r JOIN
           payments p
           ON p.id = r.reservation_id
      WHERE r.created_at >= '2008-01-01' AND
            r.status = 'closed'
      GROUP BY r.customer_id
     ) r
GROUP BY r.num_of_orders;
```